# How to resolve the problem of refreshing standard page multiple times until callout completes?

Tags: opportunity, future, ajax, inline-visualforce, actionpoller

We are using opportunity custom button to populate the value of a field based on the response form future callout. In order to  receive the value we had to keep refreshing the opportunity page until the callout gets completed and displays the result.Few sites suggested to go with apex "action poller" and inline visualforce page.Is there some other way to do it?Or if this is the only way, how can we achieve it in opportunity standard page?Sorry if my question seems to be silly.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you need to keep refreshing page in order to update the value ?